# How to search depending on location within two tables with one to many relation?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have two tables: `users` and `location`. The columns in `users` are: `id`, `name`, and `location_id`.

The columns in `location` are `id` and `city`.

There is a relation between the two tables (one to many) between `users.location_id` and `location.id`.

I want to show users that have the same location.

For example:

```
 <input type='text' name='search_input' />

 $search_input = $_POST["search_input"];

 $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * from users WHERE ... LIKE  :s');
 $stmt->bindValue(':s',  '%' . $search_input . '%'  , PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->execute();
 $values = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I want to complete the sql statement to select users that have the same location.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "users that have the same location"? Maybe show an example? How is the search input involved?

Comment: @Don'tPanic , for example I have two users jack and john , both have the location_id = 1 for example which is new york for example , I want to show both the two users when I enter new york

Comment: Okay. So you want to show all users for a specific location? Or can your query possible return multiple locations, and you want to get all users for each of those locations?

Comment: @Don'tPanic , the first case , each time only one location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one specific city, you can just join the users table to the location table.

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
        FROM users JOIN location ON users.location_id = location.id
        WHERE city = ?';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$search_input]);
$values = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The way you are doing it currently, with `LIKE`, may return more than one city, though, so you may want to add some sorting to your query to organize the results.

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
        FROM users JOIN location ON users.location_id = location.id
        WHERE city LIKE ?
        ORDER BY city.name, users.name';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(["%$search_input%"]);
$values = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

If you don't want to (possibly) match more than one location, you should use `=` rather than `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query should probably look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE location_id IN (SELECT id FROM locations WHERE id='location_id_here')
```

For this example, you'll need the location ID you're trying to look up before you perform this query, but if you have it that should work.